# Excel Combine two columns in call to function?

Tags: google-sheets, unique

My spreadsheet looks like this:
[image]

I have two lists of dates, I want to get all unique dates between Dates1 and Dates2 and put them in column C.

I can get unique dates in column A with `UNIQUE(A2:A4)`, but I want all unique dates between both columnms. When I try to do `=UNIQUE(A2:A4,B2:B5)` I get the error:

> Wrong number of arguments to UNIQUE. Expected 1 arguments, but got 2 arguments.

How can I get all unique dates between both? I've also tried concatenate, but that just gives me a huge number, not a row of dates.

Thanks!

Comment: What version of Excel are you using that has a native worksheet function called UNIQUE?

Comment: @Jeeped it's actually not excel it's https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets but I figured they were the same

Comment: Wrong. Use the correct tag for the platform you are under. If there is cross-platform conformity then use both tags but UNIQUE does not exist in Excel and that tag has no business being attached to your question.

Comment: Have you trid putting all cells on the argument? ie `UNIQUE(A2:B5)`?

Comment: @Malky.Kid Thanks that is helpful for my test example, but in my real spreadsheet the date columns are not right next to each other, so there would be tons of other random data in between

Comment: can you use a dummy column that is an exact copy of your column? and then place that dummy column next to your column?

Comment: @Malky.Kid Oh right I guess I could do that, thanks, I'll set that up. If you leave that as an answer I'll upvote it and select it if nobody can come up with a better solution, but that's good enough, thanks!

Comment: Have posted one.. glad I could help sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unique formula can only work with single column. Try this formula:

`=UNIQUE({A2:A4;B2:B5})`

`{ }` will convert 2 columns into one: `{A2:A4;B2:B5}`

See more info here:
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Put all cells on the argument ie `UNIQUE(A2:B5)`

For seperate columns, create a dummy column next to the one you are comparing to, set its contents to the actual column, then use `Unique`

Comment: On second thought this isn't actually what I need, because the call to unique puts them in seperate columns, like this, the fomrula is in E1, see how the unique data spills over into colum f, is there anyway to fix this? http://i.imgur.com/maRWJ9L.png

Answer (score 1):

Use iferror to pass processing to a second version of a 'unique list' formula with different columns.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99, A:A)), MATCH(0, COUNTIF(D$1:D1, A$2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99, A:A))), 0)),
 IFERROR(INDEX(B$2:INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1E+99, B:B)), MATCH(0, COUNTIF(D$1:D1, B$2:INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1E+99, B:B))), 0)), TEXT(,)))
```

[image]

Turns out (thanks to [Keatinge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2056979/keatinge)) that UNIQUE takes an array of ranges separated by a semi-colon and wrapped in braces. Putting the range limiters from my own solution in achieves:

```
=unique({A$2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99, A:A));C$2:INDEX(C:C, MATCH(1E+99, C:C))})
```

[image]

That sample google-sheets is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CY2xbv_GNSdfuYXKPCInHNxGXN-izasPHf-gizpXSaU/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I just found out you can use this syntax `=UNIQUE({B2:B999;G2:G999})` to combine rows much more simply

Comment: Do you know how you are getting a single column? I get two columns.

Comment: I think using a comma inside the brackets `{}` causes you to get two columns, but if you use it exactly like I posted with a semicolon inbetween both ranges it returns a single column

Comment: Ah, I thought the semi-colon was a regional list separator thing. OK, to get rid of the blank you could use the values-per-column determination as above. I'll post an updated formula using your method.